# why do we need to prevent Circular Object References

Tags: json.net, xmlserializer, datacontractserializer, serialization

I'm new to this. Can you please explain to me why the "Circular REference" is a bad thing, what's the bad result it may bring about?

Comment: Perhaps a google search would be more appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would serialize this into JSON then you would get an infinite JSON-document because at the time the Serializer serializes the `CTest` object into JSON and he reaches the `Other` property this property is referenced by itself and the serializer starts with serializing this object. And so one.

```
public class CTest
{
    public CTest Other { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

[Test]
public void Circulartest()
{
    CTest instance = new CTest();
    instance.Description = "Hello";
    instance.Other = instance;

    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(instance);
}
```

This would result in following JSON file

```
{
    "Description": "Hello"
    "Other":
    {
        "Description": "Hello"
        "Other":
        {
            "Description": "Hello"
            "Other":
            {
                "Description": "Hello"
                "Other":
                {
                    ....never ending story
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```